# How can I add a JButton to a JPanel from other class?

Tags: java, swing

So I have 2 classes. One that creates a JPanel and a JFrame, and one that creates Buttons. Now I want to add those Buttons to my JPanel.

**Where my JPanel and JFrame are created:**

```
public class Surface extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static JFrame jframe = new JFrame("TitleComingSoon");
    Snake mySnake = new Snake(true);

    int width;
    int height;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Surface(int width, int height)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        // Create the JPanel
        setLayout(null);
        setBounds(0, 0, 400, 400);
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        // Create the JFrame
        jframe.setSize(width, height);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setLayout(null);
        jframe.add(this); // Add the JPanel to the JFrame
        jframe.setVisible(true);

        // Add the KeyListener
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();

        show();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics diamond)
    {   
        super.paintComponent(diamond);
        diamond.drawRect(60, 60, 100, 50);
        diamond.setColor(Color.RED);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

**And in my other class I'm doing this:**

```
Surface.jframe.add(myButton);
```

My problem is, that the buttons is under the JPanel. So if I remove the JPanel, I can see the button.

Comment: The first thing I would change is "setLayout(null);"

Answer (score 1):

Several things jump out...

1. Use of `null` layouts. While it might seem like you gain control, you increase your work load and lose flexibility between platforms.
2. Creating a frame from with another component, but more importantly, from within its constructor. The panel shouldn't be concerned with how it will be displayed and should be focused on doing the job it was designed for.
3. Use of `KeyListener`. `KeyListener` is fussy and troublesome, better to use the Key Bindings API
4. Use of `static` for cross object communication. Static is not how you provide access to fields across classes, there are plenty of other techniques which provide better support. The main problem is, if you create another instance of your pane, you'll create a new frame and change the reference to the `static` field...now which frame are you actually addressing?

So, what's the solution?

- From your "main" entry class, create an instance of a `JFrame`, your `Surface` panel and button. Set the `Surface` panel as the content panel of the frame, then add the button to the frame.
- Make use of appropriate layout managers
- Use the key bindings API instead of `KeyListener`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of your `ButtonHolderClass` in `Surface` and retrieve the button by way of a public `getter` method:

```
public Surface(int width, int height)
{
    ...
    ButtonHolderClass buttonHolder = new ButtonHolderClass();
    JButton myButton = buttonHolder.getMyButton();
    add(myButton); // Add myButton

    jframe.add(this); // Add the JPanel to the JFrame
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Surface.jframe.add(myButton);
```

You are adding the button to the JFrame. You said you wanted to add it to the JPanel.

Simply make it

```
Surface.add(myButton);
Surface.jframe.add(Surface);
```

That will add the JButton to the JPanel, then it will add the JPanel to the JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem in ordering things here. You are adding your Surface instance to the frame before the Surface constructor is done constructing it.

```
package test;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Surface extends JPanel {
    static JFrame jframe;
    static Surface surfaceInstance = new Surface();
    public static Surface getInstance() {
        return surfaceInstance;
    }
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        /* You need this to be a good friend of the Swing */
        Runnable initiator = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                jframe = new JFrame("Whatever title you want");
                jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // this will kill the application when you close the frame
                jframe.setContentPane(Surface.getInstance());
                jframe.pack();
                jframe.setVisible(true);
            }

        };

        /** You let the Swing run your initiator when Swing wishes to do so */
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(initiator);
        Surface.getInstance().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        /** then you can add other stuff to it **/
        for (String buttonTitle: new String[] {"button1", "button2", "button3"}) {
            Surface.getInstance().add(new JButton(buttonTitle));
        }
    }
}
```